# jquery mutually get value of exclusive checkbox

Tags: jquery

Hi I need a sample code to get the value of selected checkbox. The checkboxes are mutually exclusive and I would like to get the selected checkbox value on the click of a button
Thanks

Comment: If you want to post the code you have so far we can see if we can tell you where its going wrong?

Comment: If the checkboxes are "mutually exclusive" you should be using radio buttons instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**selected checkbox??**

maybe you want checked checkbox....

html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox2" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="Checkbox3">
<input type="button" name="button1" value="see checked">
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
   $('input:button').click(function(){
      alert($('input:checkbox:checked').attr('name'));
   })
})
```

if multiple are checked

```
$(function(){
   $('input:button').click(function(){
       $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
           alert($(this).attr('name'));
       });
   })
})
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/eroco/edit)